# Change EditText width with scale animation without scaling the chars in it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an EditText and I am scaling it from 100% to 80% with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toXScale="0.8"
            android:toYScale="1.0" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

After this my text in it is scaled too. **How can I scale/change EditText width with animation without scaling the text in it**. Regards to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an answer. Here it is:

```
public class ResizeWidthAnimation extends Animation
{

private int mWidth;
private int mStartWidth;
private View mView;

public ResizeWidthAnimation(View view, int width)
{
    mView = view;
    mWidth = width;
    mStartWidth = view.getWidth();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
{
    int newWidth = mStartWidth + (int) ((mWidth - mStartWidth) * interpolatedTime);

    mView.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    mView.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight)
{
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds()
{
    return true;
}
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
    ResizeWidthAnimation anim = new ResizeWidthAnimation(editTextSearch, 500);
    anim.setDuration(400);
    editTextSearch.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this in your layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```